# MATLAB - Splitting an image converts the blocks into grayscale

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Using MATLAB, I am trying to convert a randomly sized image into four equal blocks. I am working with "for" loops to create blocks. The problem I am facing is that these blocks are being converted into gray scale whereas I want the blocks to retain their original form i.e. RGB channel. Here is the code I am using:

```
clear all;
img1 = imread('ABC.png');
[rs, cols, colorchan] = size(img1);
rnew = int32(rs/2);
cnew = int32(cols/2);

for i = 1:4
    for j = 1:4 
        imgij = img1((i-1)*rnew+1:i*rnew, (j-1)*cnew+1:j*cnew);
        figure();
        imshow(imgij);
        %do some other stuff here%
    end
end
```

I am new to MATLAB and that's the best I could do myself. Can somebody please tell me how to retain the original form of every block of the parent image? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have considered only the width and height of the image. But actually for a colour image, colour is the 3rd dimension in Matlab. Try the following code.

```
img = imread('onion.png');
figure; imshow(img);
w = size(img,2); % width of the original image
h = size(img,1); % height of the original image
wm = floor(w/2); % middle of the width
hm = floor(h/2); % middle of the height

figure;
imgtl = img(1:hm,1:wm,:); % top left image
subplot(2,2,1); imshow(imgtl);
imgtr = img(1:hm,wm+1:w,:); % top right image
subplot(2,2,2); imshow(imgtr);
imgbl = img(hm+1:h,1:wm,:); % bottom left image
subplot(2,2,3); imshow(imgbl);
imgbr = img(hm+1:h,wm+1:w,:); % bottom right image
subplot(2,2,4); imshow(imgbr);
```

Original image:

[image: Original Image]

Partitioned image:

[image: Partitioned Image]

Comment: thanks. it worked. But when i added the color dimension at the end of this line:
    imgij = img1((i-1)*rnew+1:i*rnew, (j-1)*cnew+1:j*cnew,:);
Matlab gave me this error:
"Index exceeds matrix dimensions."

Can you help me understand this too?